# Does any OS allow moving memory from one address to another without physically copying it?

Tags: c++, c, windows, linux, operating-system

memcpy/memmove duplicate (copy the data) from source to destination. Does anything exist to move pages from one virtual address to another without doing an actual byte by byte copy of the source data? It seems to be perfectly possible to me, but does any operating system actually allow this? It seems odd to me that dynamic arrays are such a widespread and popular concept but that growing them by physically copying is such a wasteful operation. It just doesn't scale when you start talking about array sizes in the gigabytes (e.g. imagine growing a 100GB array into a 200GB array. That's a problem that's entirely possible on servers in the < $10K range now.

```
void* very_large_buffer = VirtualAlloc(NULL, 2GB, MEM_COMMIT);
// Populate very_large_buffer, run out of space.
// Allocate buffer twice as large, but don't actually allocate 
// physical memory, just reserve the address space.
void* even_bigger_buffer = VirtualAlloc(NULL, 4GB, MEM_RESERVE);
// Remap the physical memory from very_large_buffer to even_bigger_buffer without copying
// (i.e. don't copy 2GB of data, just copy the mapping of virtual pages to physical pages)
// Does any OS provide support for an operation like this?    
MoveMemory(very_large_buffer, even_bigger_buffer, 2GB)
// Now very_large_buffer no longer has any physical memory pages associated with it
VirtualFree(very_large_buffer)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To some extent, you can do that with [`mremap`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mremap.2.html) on Linux.

That call plays with the process's page table to do a zero-copy reallocation *if it can*. It is not possible in all cases (address space fragmentation, and simply the presence of other existing mappings are an issue).

The man page actually says this:

> mremap() changes the mapping between virtual addresses and memory pages.  This can be used to implement a very efficient realloc(3).

Comment: This looks like it's exactly what I'm looking for. I could use this on linux and a standard dumb memory copy everywhere else.

Comment: Or a realloc and hope that it uses a similar method under the hood. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's a common use of memory mapped files to 'move' or copy memory between process by mapping different views of the file

Answer (score 1):

Every POSIX system is able to do this. If you use `mmap` with a file descriptor (obtained by `open` or `shm_open`) and not anonymously you can unmap it, then truncate (shrink or grow) and then map it again. You may and often will get a different virtual address for the same pages.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but unmapping would write all dirty pages back to that file (lazily?) So when you re-map it, accessing pages could potentially require reading them back from the file. There's a lot of implementation detail in there, but avoiding memory copies by causing disk IO is not likely to be a win. I'm curious though, since mmap is often used to share memory between processes, shouldn't it be possible to grow (not shrink) the file and create a second mapping of the same file without closing the first mapping? That would be a zero move copy I think.

Comment: First, if you use `shm_open` there is no file, so there can't anything be written to it. And even for `open` I don't think that unmapping would write back the pages, only closing the file descriptor would enforce that.

Comment: I guess in the shm_open case you would not lose the contents just because you unmapped it, that is interesting. And you're right I guess the dirty pages would not get written just because you closed the mapping, it should still be in the system write buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I mean, you'd never be able to absolutely guarantee that there would be no active memory in that next 100GB, so you might not be able to make it contiguous.

On the other hand, you could use a ragged array (an array of arrays) where the arrays do not have to be next to each other (or even the same size). Many of the advantages of dynamic arrays may not scale to the 100GB realm.

Comment: My understanding is that the actual physical RAM pages need not be contiguous, that's the point of virtual addressing. But you would need 200GB of non-fragmented virtual address space (currently 64bit processes have 8TB of address space in modern operating systems, so this should not be an issue.)